# Can't write to zip File if using a string or variant in Shell.Application Copyhere

Tags: vba, excel

I am having troubles with NameSpace CopyHere function. I am trying to create a zip file containing a bunch of logs. I can create the zip file just fine, but when using the NameSpace.CopyHere, if I use a string or a variant containing a string, it won't write the file to the zip archive.

For example, I have a file located at P:\test2.txt .

If I use those lines :

```
 objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere sFile
 objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere vLogs(i)
```

where sFile = vLogs(i) = "P:\test2.txt

the file test2.txt won't be copied in the zip archive.

However, if I use this line :

```
objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere "P:\test2.txt"
```

Then, the file gets copied in the zip file.

If I put a check to see if the sFile or vLog(i) is = "P:\test2.txt", I can see that they are the same thing.

Is there something I am missing here on why the first 2 lines don't work, but the third one does?

Thank you for your time.

Full sub :

```
Private Sub BtnSaveToZip_Click()
Dim bEndRow, bTest As Boolean
Dim iRow, iCount As Integer
Dim sZipArchive, sDate, sFolderExists, sFile As String
Dim vLogs, vFilename As Variant
Dim objApp As Object

sDate = Date
sDate = Replace(sDate, "/", "") ' set date format to DDMMYYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY
sZipArchive = LblLogArchive + "\" + sDate
sFolderExists = Dir(sZipArchive)
If sFolderExists = "" Then
    CreateDir (sZipArchive) ' if the subfolder with the date does not exists, create it
End If
sZipArchive = sZipArchive + "\" + wsContacts.Range("B7").Value + " Logs_" + sDate + ".zip"
'Check if file is open
If FileLocked(sZipArchive) Then
    MsgBox sZipArchive + " already open. Please close the archive."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Creating the zip file from Ron de Bruin
NewZip (sZipArchive)

'filling the zip file
Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

bEndRow = False
iRow = gFirstData
Do While bEndRow = False
    If Not IsEmpty(wsLogs.Cells(iRow, gTestCase).Value) Then
        If Not IsEmpty(wsLogs.Cells(iRow, gLog).Value) Then
            vLogs = Split(wsLogs.Cells(iRow, gLog).Value, ";")
            For i = 0 To UBound(vLogs) - 1
                sFile = vLogs(i) ' Debug only
                If sFile = "P:\test2.txt" Then 'Debug only
                objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere vLogs(i) ' if I put "P:\test2.txt", it works correctly
                'Keep script waiting 5s for debug purpose
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
                End If
            Next
        End If
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Else
        bEndRow = True
    End If
Loop
MsgBox "Zip successfully created"
Set objApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try declaring `sFile` as `Variant` rather than `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this works

```
objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere "P:\test2.txt"
```

and `sFile` and `vLogs(i)` appears to be the same as `P:\test2.txt` then I believe it could be a leading or trailing space problem. Try this

```
objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere Trim(sFile)
```

or

```
objApp.Namespace(sZipArchive).CopyHere Trim(vLogs(i))
```

The other way to check if `sFile` and `vLogs(i)` contains a valid path is by using `DIR`

One more way of debugging is to step through your code and then type this in the Immediate window

```
?=vLogs(i)="P:\test2.txt"
?=sFile="P:\test2.txt"
```

You should get a true in both cases. If you don't then there is your problem :)

Comment: When I added Trim(), it worked. But if there is some leading/trailing space problem, then why does the check if sFile="P:\test2.txt" returns true?

Comment: I am not sure. It shouldn't return true if there are leading or trailing spaces :)